# Still getting pop up notifications in Calendar / Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: notification, calendar

Hello I have "Do not disturb" turned ON and in Settings -> Notifications I do not have calendar app. I am still getting annoying pop up notifications about calendar events. I do not use the calendar at all, how can I disable calendar notifications or better yet, whole calendar?

Comment: Got the same issue on 22.10.